# What does dream about killing birds who are attacking you signify?

Tags: dream

What does dream about killing birds who are attacking you (inside your house)  signify. Is it auspicious and does it have a spiritual connection?

Comment: Dream questions with regards to spirituality - even if we give answer from scriptures, it wont be helpful because what happens in dream, = your karma, your situation in house all matters. Only a Guru can tell what you saw was just a play of mind or spiritual evolution. That's why dream questions are here off topic for site!